# CountDownTimer not counting down but jumping straight to finish() method

Tags: android, timer, onclick, countdowntimer

I have an app that I am creating that will eventually, be a countdown timer with multiple stores of times so that the user will select the one to use and then start the countdowntimer. The issue that I am having is that the call to the `countDownTimer.start();` works but the timer jumps to the `onfinish()`. I placed log.i's within the override onTick function and those Log.i's did not appear in logcat, which leads me to believe that something went wrong in the logic and that the countdowntimer method did not see something to count down and dropped to the onfinish.

That being said, please see the entire app below:

```
    package com.vertygoeclypse.multitimer;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.CountDownTimer;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.NumberPicker;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener, OnClickListener{
Button dgbtn, abbtn, exbtn, cvbtn, canlbtn, sbtbtn, starest;
EditText tagvalue;
TextView tgview, minview, secview, timeRemaining;
NumberPicker minnp, secnp;
Dialog cusd;
private MultiCountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long timeElapsed;
private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
private TextView timeElapsedView;
long startTime;
long interval=100;
long coversionvalues=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dgbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
    abbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbtn);
    exbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exitbtn);
    cvbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clrvaluesbtn);
    starest =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.startresetbtn);
    tgview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tagview);
    minview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minview);
    secview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.seecview);
    timeRemaining = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeremainingview);
    timeElapsedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countdowntimer);
    dgbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    abbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    exbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    cvbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    starest.setOnClickListener(this);
    countDownTimer = new MultiCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    if(startTime==0){
        starest.setEnabled(false);
    }else if(startTime>0){
        starest.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.dialogbtn:
        showDialog();
        break;
    case R.id.exitbtn:
        finish();
    case R.id.clrvaluesbtn:
        tgview.setText("");
        minview.setText("");
        secview.setText("");
        break;
    case R.id.cancelbtn:
        cusd.dismiss();
    case R.id.submitbtn:
        tgview.setText(String.valueOf(tagvalue.getText()));
        minview.setText(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        secview.setText(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue()));
        int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue()));
        int val3 = (val1*60)*1000;
        int val4 = val2*1000;
        coversionvalues = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(val3+val4));
        startTime = coversionvalues;
        starest.setEnabled(true);
        cusd.dismiss(); 
        break;
    case R.id.startresetbtn:
        if(!timerHasStarted){
                countDownTimer.start();
                timerHasStarted = true;
                starest.setText("Start");
        } else {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            timerHasStarted = false;
            starest.setText("Reset");
        }
    }
}
public void showDialog(){
    cusd = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    cusd.setTitle("Tag and Timer Selector");
    cusd.setContentView(R.layout.dialogbox);
    canlbtn = (Button) cusd.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);
    sbtbtn = (Button) cusd.findViewById(R.id.submitbtn);        
    minnp = (NumberPicker) cusd.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
    secnp = (NumberPicker) cusd.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    tagvalue = (EditText) cusd.findViewById(R.id.tagname);
    canlbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    sbtbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    minnp.setMaxValue(59);
    minnp.setMinValue(0);
    minnp.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    minnp.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    secnp.setMaxValue(59);
    secnp.setMinValue(0);
    secnp.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    secnp.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    cusd.show();
}
public class MultiCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer{
    public MultiCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval)
    {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        Log.i("VertygoEclypse", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished));
        timeRemaining.setText("Time remain:" + millisUntilFinished);
        timeElapsed = startTime - millisUntilFinished;
        Log.i("VertygoEclypse", String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(timeElapsed));
    }
@Override
public void onFinish()
    {
        timeRemaining.setText("Time's up!");
        timeElapsedView.setText("Time Elapsed: " + String.valueOf(startTime));
    }
}
    }
```

Comment: A possible situation is that the `startTime` contains no value in it. Have you tried debugging it checked the values at run-time? I copied the required code to run the timer and set the value of `startTime` to `5000`, and it did work for me.

Comment: Hi Joel, I have the startTime set from values that I get in a dialog box. the code `int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue()));
        int val3 = (val1*60)*1000;
        int val4 = val2*1000;
        coversionvalues = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(val3+val4));
        startTime = coversionvalues;` shows this. and I have placed Log.i just before the call and it returned the correct value. Is there something I am missing.

Comment: The original example showed setTime as being `private final long startTime=50000;` but I needed to have this variable be set to a dynamic value based on the users requirements.

Comment: I tried your code including the dialog box and it works fine for me. I still think that `startTime` isn't receiving the value in your implementation. Just add breakpoints and check for values at run-time.

Comment: I had Log.i before the call to start() and after the return. showing the value of startTime. The place that I do not get Log.i messages is from within the onTick() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For startTime set some value, It cannot be zero. Actually startTime is the time in future when the countdown timer should stop or finish. if possible please change it to finish time

```
countDownTimer = new MultiCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
```

Comment: Hi Sush, The code that you saw above, is a replica of code form an example and I simply modified it. The startTime is not zero at the time of the call. The following code shows this: `int val1 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(minnp.getValue()));
        int val2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secnp.getValue())); int val3 = (val1*60)*1000; int val4 = val2*1000; coversionvalues = Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(val3+val4));
startTime = coversionvalues;` also I placed some Log.i within the onTick event that do not show up in Logcat, this tells me that the ontick is not called.

Comment: Yes, where ur setting to countdown timer.

Comment: there is no code which the sets counter start time, sorry its finish time. not starttime.

Comment: ok Sush, I am very new to android programming, and I am trying to understand what you are saying but it is just flying over my head, could you provide me with an example to what you are speaking about.

Comment: Yes I am trying to use a countdowntimer and not a timer. I want to set the value to say 50000, and use an interval of 1000 and have the countdowntimer, count down to 0.

Comment: @cchinchoy yes ur right, but for countdowntimer u have to set while creating only. not after words. more over i m not finding any code where ur creating it. other than at the starting

Comment: @sush He's setting the value of `startTime` (or countdown timer as you ask) using a dialog. He has buttons that needs to be pressed first which will allow the user to set the time.

Comment: @JoelFernandes startTime = coversionvalues;
        starest.setEnabled(true);
        cusd.dismiss(); with this code he is just enabling the some button, where is new operator or coustructor call to create countdowntimer with values. ?

Comment: Sush, the `startTime = coversionvalues;` sets the value for the startTime to be used within the countDownTimer. The call to the countDownTimer is within a switch case to the if of the button to start the countdown. `case R.id.startresetbtn:
   if(!timerHasStarted){
   countDownTimer.start();
   timerHasStarted = true;
   starest.setText("Start");
   } else {
   countDownTimer.cancel();
   timerHasStarted = false;
   starest.setText("Reset");
   }` I belive my issue may be that the variable declared startTime is not private static final.

Comment: The example that I pulled it from. the variable startTime was declared as `private static final startTime=50000;` and this works. how do I make this declaration that it will allow me to set the value dynamically.

Comment: sorry.. u have misstaken or i might be. but there is call to super constructor in the countdowntimer right ? ur code must create new constuctor every time. start is just api to start it.

Comment: yes it has a constructor `super(startTime, interval);` ok I believe that I am understanding, so with the constructor being called how do I create a new constructor everytime so that the start() functions. Also, why does it work when I at the `private static final startTiem = 50000;`.

Comment: i telling u its not starttime its finish time, means u set big time when countdown timer should stop, and interval is a callback for u, interms of small units of you big finish time. you have set it in the new operator itself while construvcting it

Comment: Ok guys, I got it to set when I declared the variable as static final but no value and then when the dialog returns with the values sets the startTime at that point. but the timer works once and then I cannot clear it. I believe that I need a new approach but for the question the answer was clear. thanks for all the assistance guys.